# User-written program winsor by Nick Cox: determining p

Tags: command, stata

I would like to use the `winsor` command written by Nick Cox. According to this page http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2011-09/msg01340.html the author states that the usual percentile of winsorizing is 1/99 and 5/95.

Am I correct that p(0.1) corresponds to the 1/99 percentile winsorizing? or is it p(0.01)?
The latter seems more intuitive, however the value p(0.5) would yield the average (which make no sense in this case).

Thank you very much.

EDIT: I am sorry, I tried p(0.5) and it does not work. Therefore, I guess p(0.01) corresponds to 1/99 and p(0.05) to 5/95 percentile.
EDIT2: I am sorry for the misunderstanding. I have misinterepreted the author´s procedure of handling outliers (drawing boxplots in order to identify points beyond the
1/99 or 5/95 percentiles).

Comment: I guess I'm the authority on what I said, but regardless of that the part of my post which you cite in your first paragraph bears **almost no resemblance** to what you report. It reports what I personally prefer for boxplot cutoffs, and says nothing about what is "usual" in Winsorizing. Regardless of that, there is no need to resort to intuition or guesswork here. The option is documented: "`p(#)` specifies the fraction of the observations to be modified in each tail. `p` should be greater than 0 and less than 0.5" N.B. less than 0.5. Also, a fraction of 0.5 would correspond to the median.

Comment: Note that this question is nothing to do with programming. It's about the OP's (mis)understanding of some software documentation.

Comment: Dear Nick, thank you for pointing it out and ensuring that I understand it correctly. After trying out different examples I could figure out that I was wrong in the beginning. Thank you for the programm and your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0.1 corresponds to winsorising at 10th and 90th percentile:

```
  . sysuse auto
        (1978 Automobile Data)   
  . sum price , detail

                                Price
    -------------------------------------------------------------
          Percentiles      Smallest
     1%         3291           3291
     5%         3748           3299
    10%         3895           3667       Obs                  74
    25%         4195           3748       Sum of Wgt.          74

    50%       5006.5                      Mean           6165.257
                            Largest       Std. Dev.      2949.496
    75%         6342          13466
    90%        11385          13594       Variance        8699526
    95%        13466          14500       Skewness       1.653434
    99%        15906          15906       Kurtosis       4.819188

    . winsor price , p(0.1) gen(wp)

    . sum wp, detail

                    price, Winsorized fraction .1
    -------------------------------------------------------------
          Percentiles      Smallest
     1%         3895           3895
     5%         3895           3895
    10%         3895           3895       Obs                  74
    25%         4195           3895       Sum of Wgt.          74

    50%       5006.5                      Mean           5997.432
                            Largest       Std. Dev.      2434.708
    75%         6342          11385
    90%        11385          11385       Variance        5927804
    95%        11385          11385       Skewness       1.294202
    99%        11385          11385       Kurtosis        3.29362
```

Comment: Usually a comment like this is not needed, but for completeness I confirm that this is the correct interpretation of my program.

Comment: Dear Dimitiriy, thank you for the example, especially for showing how to exmaine the differences. It was very helpful for the use of my data! (especially for pointing out why I winsorize at x/1-x percentile).